# DataBinding: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List ... does not contain a property with the name X.X

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, webforms

I have:
 - EF6 (First Code);
 - ASP.NET v4.5.2 (Webforms);
 - On UI simple GUI (on Page directive Async="true"):

```
    <form>
    <UpdatePanel>
    <Gridview Selected="ShowAll">
  <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
    </Gridview>
    </UpdatePanel>
    </form>
```

Code behind:

```
public IEnumerable ShowAll()
{
    return CustomerRepository.GetAllAsync().Result;
}
```

And this is GetAllAsync():

```
public static async Task<List<Customer>> GetAllAsync()
{
    using (var dbCon = new DbContext())
    {
        return await dbCon.Note.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

The problems is when it's starts it shows me an error:
A field or property with the name 'Header' was not found on the selected data source if I use **BoundField** and if I use **ItemTemplate** get's the error which in the title of this post.

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: Looks like the databinding system doesn't handle async code. Also, async/await on the `ShowAll` method is just overhead, you can remove both, shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: But when I use return CustomerRepository.GetAllAsync().Result; The page just all the time trying to load and nothing happened.

Comment: Maybe it is pulling some stuff from the database? If it doesn't break, just wait for some time.

Comment: Also, there is not enough information in this post for us to reproduce the issue. Please edit your question to make it possible for us to do so.

Comment: I don't know how ASP.NET handles async code (or even if it does), but the fact that the error message says that there is no such property on a *Task* object means that it did not wait for the task to complete and thus obtain the final results, which means it did not know how to handle async code. *How* to fix this, I have no idea, I'm no asp.net expert.

Comment: Since your edit, your title doesn't match your actual question. Please take the time to edit your question.

Comment: I've changed my 1st post. Look at ShowAll() return method. And no I've been wating for 5 min nothing... I have only 1 row in my Database

Comment: When you step through this in the debugger, does `CustomerRepository.GetAllAsync().Result` have any data?

Comment: Yes it has, all my data in it

Answer (score 1):

You need ASP.NET **4.6** for [asynchronous model binding on webforms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/06/11/cool-web-forms-features-in-2015-async-model-binding.aspx). So the easiest way to do this is to upgrade and then return a `Task<T>` from your code behind:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable> ShowAll()
{
  return await CustomerRepository.GetAllAsync();
}
```

Note that using `Task<T>.Result` will not work; it causes a [deadlock situation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I describe in full on my blog.

If you're not ready to upgrade yet, then you *can* use `RegisterAsyncTask`, but the data binding isn't quite as natural; this requires you to explicitly set the `DataSource` and whatnot at the end of your `ShowAll` method. See [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45) for an example of asynchronous webforms in a .NET 4.5 environment. I would recommend upgrading if possible, since the new asynchronous data-binding syntax is more natural IMO.